# Emulator not getting started. Shows Errors

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When i run the android emulator i am facing the following errors in the event log.. so the emulator not getting started

```
Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio'

Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio output failed

Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'

Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed

Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `dac'

Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: Unable to open C:\Users\user8\.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_22.avd\data\misc\pstore\pstore.bin: Permission denied
```

System Configuration :
I used android studio latest version 3.0.1,
Windows 7 - 64 bit

I searched lot related to this error.. can't find suitable solution .. can anyone help me..

Answer (score 0):

right click on `\pstore\` folder then select properties option Now uncheck `Read Only` option  and restart Studio

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\Users\user8.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_22.avd\data\misc, make right click on pstore, pick Properties and uncheck box Only for reading (Title may be a little different). This is a new non critical bug , you should not attach importance to this.

Try this soulution it is basically permission issue.

Comment: I tried already.. it resolves only the last error i mentioned.. but remaining errors unchanged..

Comment: read this discussion https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37074416 this will help you